# Can we write @Component or any other annotations on DTO classes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I am working with Spring Restful and Hibernate. To remove the redundancy in code I want to avoid the object creation of DTO in each and every methods and want to declare it with @Component annotation, I want to know is there any specific rules for DTOs as we have some guidelines for POJO and JavaBeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Check Spring Doc

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-stereotype-annotations

7.10.1 @Component and further stereotype annotations

Spring provides further stereotype annotations: @Component, @Service, and @Controller. @Component is a generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component. @Repository, @Service, and @Controller are specializations of @Component for more specific use cases, for example, in the persistence, service, and presentation layers, respectively. Therefore, you can annotate your component classes with @Component, but by annotating them with @Repository, @Service, or @Controller instead, your classes are more properly suited for processing by tools or associating with aspects. For example, these stereotype annotations make ideal targets for pointcuts. It is also possible that @Repository, @Service, and @Controller may carry additional semantics in future releases of the Spring Framework. Thus, if you are choosing between using @Component or @Service for your service layer, @Service is clearly the better choice. Similarly, as stated above, @Repository is already supported as a marker for automatic exception translation in your persistence layer.

Comment: No such rule to use component but if your class not included in persistence, service, and presentation layers then you can use @Component

Comment: Okay thanks for the above information but i m asking is their any guidelines for DTO classes?

Comment: No such guideline to use Component. any Class level beans can be created using Component as I worked on projects. because all are just stereotype annotations.

Comment: @VivekNerle I believe this is not the answer to the question. The question is clearly about DTO while in the answer nothing mentioned about it. BTW, the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static method which returns the Object of your DTO class and you can call this method from anywhere to get the instance of that class like this..

```
private DTOObject dtoObject;
public static DTOObject getInstance() {
    if(dtoObject == null) {
        dtoObject = new DTOObject();
    }
    return dtoOject;
}
```